Time is double encoding while passing more than 2 parameters in the url iOS17
NSString *queryString = @"last_updated_time=2024-04-29T10%3A27%3A07%2B0000&type[]=763&order_date=2024-04-29";

// Encode the query string

NSString *encodedQueryString = [queryString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

// Check if the URL already contains a query string

NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
NSString *separator = [urlString rangeOfString:@"?"].location == NSNotFound ? @"?" : @"&";

// Construct the final URL string

NSString *finalURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", urlString, separator, queryString];

// Create the NSURL object

NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[finalURLString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];

The time is double encodeing for the above logic.
Excpeted URL:
path.json?last_updated_time=2024-04-29T10%3A41%3A13%2B0000&type%5B%5D=763&order_date=2024-04-29
Actual URL:
path.json?last_updated_time=2024-04-29T10%253A41%253A13%252B0000&type%5B%5D=763&order_date=2024-04-29
It appears that the issue arises only when passing more than two parameters in the URL. Do you have any suggestions on how to address this problem specifically in iOS 17?

Please add the tag for the programming language that you're using.
